# Apple watch app wont build due to error "Failed to use existing instance 0 for app with bundle identifier: com.apple.Carousel"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-watch, watchos

I recently re-paired my apple watch 3. Upgraded xcode to 11.1, and upgraded to macOS Catalina.

When I try run an app on my apple watch, it will install, but before it finishes building, it fails with the error "Failed to use existing instance 0 for app with bundle identifier: com.apple.Carousel"

I'm not sure where that bundle identifier comes from, how it got changed, or how to go about changing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Carousel is the Apple Watch system shell. I encountered this same issue, then reported it in Feedback Assistant (FB6117770). Apple responded saying "We are unable to reproduce the issue you reported. Please try restarting your iPhone, watch, and Xcode and then attempt to connect to your Mac again. Did this resolve the issue?" After doing this, I no longer encountered the error.